# Problem with Item Added Event Receiver firing five times, not one

Tags: 2010, 2013, event-receivers

I am using an Event Receiver, which should synchronize two Lists, But it is firing five times instead of one, and makes 5 records, not one.

Why is it firing 5 times?

```
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            if (properties.List.Title == "Jawna")
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Niejawna"];
                        SPListItem item = lstOtherList.Items.Add();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        item["A"] = properties.AfterProperties["A"];
                        item["B"] = properties.AfterProperties["B"];
                        item["Status"] = properties.AfterProperties["Status"];
                        item.Update();

                    }
                }
            }
            if (properties.List.Title == "Niejawna")
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Jawna"];
                        SPListItem item = lstOtherList.Items.Add();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        item["A"] = properties.AfterProperties["A"];
                        item["B"] = properties.AfterProperties["B"];
                        item["Status"] = properties.AfterProperties["Status"];
                        item.Update();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code it seems you are using the same code for handling `ItemAdded` on both the lists. So what is happening is on inserting item in 1 list is inserting an item into the second list. And this invokes the event receiver in Second list.

Two possibilities.

1. You might have attached the same event receiver 5 times - You can review this using SharePoint Manager or PowerShell.

   ```
   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

   $site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://siteurl"
   $web = $site.RootWeb
   $list = $web.Lists["Jawna"]
   $list.EventReceivers | Select assembly, name, type

   $site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://siteurl"
   $web = $site.RootWeb
   $list = $web.Lists["Niejawna"]
   $list.EventReceivers | Select assembly, name, type
   ```
2. Disable Event Firing when update is made inside the Receiver.

   ```
   //Do this on Start of the handler
   this.EventFiringEnabled =false;

   //Do this on End of the handler
   this.EventFiringEnabled =true;
   ```

So your final code will look like

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    this.EventFiringEnabled =false;
    base.ItemAdded(properties);
    if (properties.List.Title == "Jawna")
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Niejawna"];
                SPListItem item = lstOtherList.Items.Add();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                item["A"] = properties.AfterProperties["A"];
                item["B"] = properties.AfterProperties["B"];
                item["Status"] = properties.AfterProperties["Status"];
                item.Update();

            }
        }
    }
    if (properties.List.Title == "Niejawna")
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Jawna"];
                SPListItem item = lstOtherList.Items.Add();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                item["A"] = properties.AfterProperties["A"];
                item["B"] = properties.AfterProperties["B"];
                item["Status"] = properties.AfterProperties["Status"];
                item.Update();

            }
        }
    }
    this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Disable Event Firing when you're making the update to the item.

See [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/programmatically-disable-event-firing-on-list-item-update-in/) for an example.

Make sure you don't leave the events disabled, though!  Wrap the code in a try, catch, finally that ends with re-enabling the events.

```
try
{
    this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
    // Your updating code...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle exception
}
finally
{
    this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this could be because the event receiver is registered multiple times. But to me, it looks like this is happening because you have this ItemAdded event receiver registered for both the "Jawna" and the "Niejawna" lists and you're basically trying to create copies of items between the two lists.

To get around this you should disable event firing when you add the item to the list and update it. And you should also place your allowing of unsafe updates and event firing disabling into a try catch block in case something goes wrong.

Try this:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);

    string otherListTitle = String.Empty;
    if (properties.List.Title == "Jawna")
        otherListTitle = "Niejawna";
    else if (properties.List.Title == "Niejawna")
        otherListTitle = "Jawna"

    if (!otherListTitle.IsNullOrEmpty)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists[otherListTitle];

                try
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
                    SPListItem item = lstOtherList.Items.Add(); 
                    item["A"] = properties.AfterProperties["A"];
                    item["B"] = properties.AfterProperties["B"];
                    item["Status"] = properties.AfterProperties["Status"];
                    item.Update();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {               
                }
                finally
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```